# How to check if a tag has image in it using Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var squares = document.querySelectorAll('td');
var img1 = document.createElement("img");
img1.src = "Group 1.svg";
var img2 = document.createElement('img');
img2.src = "Ellipse 1.svg";

function changeMarker() {
  if (this.textContent == '') {
    this.appendChild(img1);
  } else if (childElements[this].localName != null) {
    this.appendChild(img2);
  } else {
    this.textContent = '';
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].childNode.addEventListener('click', changeMarker);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Can you be a bit more specific here? Don’t just show a snippet of code, and rely on the title only, to transport what you actually want. Do you want to check for just any image? A specific one with a certain src URL? …?

Answer (score 0):

The method `.getElementsByTagName` is available for you to use. Since we get the container first then call that element's copy of this method, we just look inside it and ignore the rest of the document.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);
function onLoaded(evt)
{
    let d1 = byId('div1');
    let d2 = byId('div2');

    let imgCount1 = d1.getElementsByTagName('img').length;
    let imgCount2 = d2.getElementsByTagName('img').length;

    d1.textContent += ` - Img Count: ${imgCount1}`;
    d2.textContent += ` - Img Count: ${imgCount2}`;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='div1'>No image</div>
    <div id='div2'>2 images<img><img></div>
    <img><img><img>
</body>
</html>
```